# Python speech_recognition IF Speech not recognised

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am a Portuguese High Schooler so sorry if I dont make myself very clear but I will try my best to explain my problem.
So for this project I need to make a program that recognises speech and do what is told to do. But if the speech is not recognisable I want the program to try until it finally catches what is being said. However I dont really know how to do that since this "error" keeps appearing: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnHjM.png)

Here is the code if anyone wants to help:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess as sp
import os

def ouvir_microfone():

   audio_Input = sr.Recognizer()

   with sr.Microphone() as source:
           
               Ray = "ON"
               Open = "Open"

               print("Hello my name is Ray pleased to help you")

               audio_Input.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
               print("Say something: ")
               audio = audio_Input.listen(source)
               
               frase = audio_Input.recognize_google(audio,language='en-US')

               if ValueError: print("Speech not recognised")
               else: print("You said: " + frase)

               if Open in frase:
                   print('sucess') 
ouvir_microfone()
```

Comment: You don't want to use `if ValueError` but `try: ... except ValueError: ...`. Read about [catching exceptions here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess as sp
import os

def ouvir_microfone():

    audio_Input = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
        Ray = "ON"
        Open = "Open"

        print("Hello my name is Ray pleased to help you")

        audio_Input.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Say something: ")
        audio = audio_Input.listen(source)
        try:
            # valid
            frase = audio_Input.recognize_google(audio,language='en-US')
            print("You said: " + frase)
        except: 
            # google could not validate
            print("Speech not recognised")
            return False

        if Open in frase:
            print('sucess') 
        return True
while True:
    if ouvir_microfone():
        # got a valid response
        break
```

Works as a solid template. Some imports also remain unused as a sidenote. Catch the exception and return False if the speech could not be recognized so it retries. The google voice recognition python library throws an exception in the case that no distinguishable speech can be read.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it amazes me how fast Og programmers can resolve a problem (even if is a basic one like this), again Thank You, and about the import I will use them for later haha thei are there just so I can remeber in the future

Answer (score 1):

Use try and exception to handle the error

```
   try:
        frase = audio_Input.recognize_google(audio,language='en-US')
        print("You said: " + frase)
    except ValueError: 
        print("Speech not recognised")
    if Open in frase:
        print('sucess')
```

Comment: Thank You for the help it work just fine, Wish i could upvote your comment but it seems my account is still to recent haha